# Connect SharePoint Lists with OData

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, odata

I have a DataSet, I have created an Excel spreadsheet using OData connection. Now I want to create a SharePoint List using this Excel data. I want the Excel and SharePoint List to be sync so that list has all the latest updates. Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: To reiterate, my question is to find if there is a way to get external data into a SharePoint List in Office 365. My plan was to import external dataset into Excel using oData connection and then sync this Excel to SharePoint list. But seems like this doesn't work as expected. Please let me know if there is a better solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by appending this to the end of the URL: `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc`

For example: `https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/somedept/Reports/MyList/_vti_bin/listdata.svc`

In Excel, choose External Data Connections > OData and enter the URL. Excel will  prompt you to select the table you want.

Here is more information about what you can do with SharePoint Online and OData:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx#bk_supported

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In order to synchronize Excel data with SharePoint, you need to convert a range of data into a table. The moment you create the table, Excel will show you an extra button to "Publish". Also if you want to synchronize Excel  with SharePoint, you need to Install the Excel Addin. here i have provided the link for SharePoint 2007 addin. If you are working in any other version you can use that.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9345

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried adding the add-in, but the odata connection to the excel sheet is lost as I have to save the excel as 97-2003 workbook in order to make publish and sync between Excel and List to work.

Comment: Try using the latest addin instead of the older version, Add addin for your SharePoint version.